# Trying to make view remember the ClientID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, methods

Im making an application using EF for a simple domain name management. It containts Clients, Domains and TLD types in the Database.

I have created controllers that allow me to create Clients, Domains and TLDs in my DB separately. What I'm trying to achieve is possibility to add the Domain directly under Client's page to avoid selecting ClientID everytime I create a new domain name and minimise the amounts of pages to go through in order to create a new Domain name in DB.

So far here are the models I'm using :

```
Klient (client model) :

public class Klient
    {
    public int KlientID { get; set; }
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    public string Firma { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Domena> Domeny { get; set; }
    }
```

Domena (domain model) :

```
    public class Domena
{
    public int DomenaID { get; set; }
    public int TLDID { get; set; }
    public int KlientID { get; set; }
    public string Nazwa { get; set; }
    public virtual TLD TLD { get; set; }
    public virtual Klient Klient { get; set; }
}
```

TLD (tlds model) :

```
   public class TLD
{
    public int TLDID { get; set; }
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public int Cena { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Domena> Domeny { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method which allows me to create the new domain name is :

```
       // GET: /Domena/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
        ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "Firma");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Domena/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Domena domena)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Domeny.Add(domena);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ", domena.TLDID);
        ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "Imie", domena.KlientID);
        return View(domena);
    }
```

And that's the fieldset of create view :

```
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Domena</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TLDID, "TLD")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("TLDID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TLDID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KlientID, "Klient")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("KlientID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KlientID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nazwa)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nazwa)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nazwa)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Right, what I want to do is a create a new method under DomenaController(where the above Create method is located at) called Add_Domain and new View for that Add_Domain method, which will allow me to create a new domain name under currently viewed client. So I want to run the app and go to /Clients/Index click details on Client with lets say ID = 6 so I'm now viewing Clients/Details/6. On this page I've added the following action link :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Domain", "Add_Domain", "Domena", new { id = Model.KlientID })
```

Which gives me weird link : 
    /Klient/Add_Domain?Length=6
instead of :
    /Domain/Add_Domain/6
However, when I delete the "new {id = Model.KlientID }" bit it creates normal link though...

Anyway, how do I modify the GET and POST httpPost so I wont have to choose the client from the list and the domain name will be added to the client from which I clicked the Add_Domain method ?

EDIT : 
RouteConfig

```
   public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Link problem is now fixed, thank you very much. The other part of the question remain : How should the new Add_Domain method described above look like (GET and POST) ? - it should take the value of the KlientID instead of displaying the list of Clients to choose from.

Comment: Can you post a routes configuration of the project ?

Comment: @StringBuilder , added to my question at the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for more information.

Comment: @Patrick, sorry for that and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action link is using an incorrect signature:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,      // "Add Domain"
    string actionName,    // "Add_Domain"
    Object routeValues,   // "Domena"
    Object htmlAttributes // new { id = Model.KlientID }
)
```

You should use [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Add Domain",
    "Add_Domain",
    "Domena",
    new { id = Model.KlientID },
    null)
```

This should give you the output you are expecting.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. This will sort out the link, any ideas how to modify the Create method above in order to create the domain directly to the KlientID given in ActionLink ? Thanks.